# Bayesian updating of log-normal parameter after observation of poisson process

Tags: bayesian, inference, poisson-distribution, likelihood, fractional-factorial

I am trying to update my estimate of a parameter (error rate) which has a prior log-normal distribution using an observation of errors (presumed to be Poisson distributed). However, I am having some trouble with how to implement my observation.

Using Bayes' Theorem, my posterior will be proportional to the product of the likelihood of my observation and the prior distribution,
$$
P(\lambda | obs) \propto P(obs|\lambda) P(\lambda),
$$
where $\lambda$ is the error rate and $obs$ is my observed data. Since the prior is log-normal, its pdf is
$$
P(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{(\ln\lambda - \ln\lambda_0)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right).
$$
The likelihood of my observation (in case of one single data point) should be
$$
P(obs|\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!},
$$
where $x$ is the error rate that I have observed.

I hope everything is correct so far. Now, the problem I have is that the error rate is given in faults per year, and the observation consists of one fault in a 35 year observation period. This means $x\approx 0.0286$, and I cannot plug that straight into the Poisson likelihood function (because of the factorial). Is it ok to use the Gamma function instead of the factorial, or should I transform my variable $\lambda$ somehow?

Comment: I think your log-normal distribution must be like $
P(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{(\ln{(\lambda) - \lambda_0})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right).
$

not $
P(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{(\ln{(\lambda - \lambda_0)})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right).
$

Comment: @masoud But I want the median of the log-normal to be $\lambda_0$, not $\exp(\lambda_0)$. So in that case, would I need to use $P(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{(\ln\lambda - \ln\lambda_0)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$?

Comment: ,I think ,It is OK! now

Comment: I have edited the expression for the prior pfd. Now it should be correct.

Comment: The poisson is a distribution of counts, not counts divided by something. You have 1 count in 35 years and you have two choices; either treat that as 35 observations of annual Poissons (one of which has a value of 1 and the rest are all 0's) or alternatively you change your period to 35 years. (Well, there are other options, but they're more work.)